# Reject Incoming Call in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, incoming-call

How to detect and reject `incoming calls` in `flutter`  even if the app is in background. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you solve that? I'm trying to build an app that will show more details about person which is calling to you (based on incoming call phone number)

Comment: I didn't find any related plugin in flutter. I used [Platform Channel](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) for my task.

Comment: Is there a chance to share that code? I'm trying to create app that will show additional info about caller. The main problem is to start app when call starts or at least leave app on background.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't actually have code  with me and that was not working properly too. May be this class could be helpful for you [PhoneStateListener Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener).

Answer (score -1):

Package:

https://pub.dev/packages/notification_incoming_call

Docs:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notification_incoming_call/notification_incoming_call.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _uuid = Uuid();
  var _currentUuid;
  var textEvents = "";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listenerEvent();
  }

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> listenerEvent() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    // We also handle the message potentially returning null.
    try {
      NotificationIncomingCall.onEvent.listen((event) {
        print(event);
        if (!mounted) return;
        switch (event!.name) {
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_INCOMING:
            // TODO: received an incoming call
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_START:
            // TODO: started an outgoing call
            // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT:
            // TODO: accepted an incoming call
            // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_DECLINE:
            // TODO: declined an incoming call
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_ENDED:
            // TODO: ended an incoming/outgoing call
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_TIMEOUT:
            // TODO: missed an incoming call
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_CALLBACK:
            // TODO: only Android - click action `Call back` from missed call notification
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_TOGGLE_HOLD:
            // TODO: only iOS
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_TOGGLE_MUTE:
            // TODO: only iOS
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_TOGGLE_DMTF:
            // TODO: only iOS
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_TOGGLE_GROUP:
            // TODO: only iOS
            break;
          case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_TOGGLE_AUDIO_SESSION:
            // TODO: only iOS
            break;
        }
        setState(() {
          textEvents += "${event.toString()}\n";
        });
      });
    } on Exception {}
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin example app'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.call,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                this.makeFakeCallInComing();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.call_end,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                this.endCurrentCall();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.call_made,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                this.startOutGoingCall();
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.call_merge,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                this.activeCalls();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
                ),
                child: Text('$textEvents'),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> makeFakeCallInComing() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7), () async {
      this._currentUuid = _uuid.v4();
      var params = <String, dynamic>{
        'id': _currentUuid,
        'nameCaller': 'Hien Nguyen',
        'appName': 'Callkit',
        'avatar': 'https://i.pravatar.cc/100',
        'handle': '0123456789',
        'type': 0,
        'duration': 30000,
        'extra': <String, dynamic>{'userId': '1a2b3c4d'},
        'headers': <String, dynamic>{'apiKey': 'Abc@123!', 'platform': 'flutter'},
        'android': <String, dynamic>{
          'isCustomNotification': true,
          'isShowLogo': false,
          // 'ringtonePath': 'ringtone_default',
          'backgroundColor': '#0955fa',
          'background': 'https://i.pravatar.cc/500',
          'actionColor': '#4CAF50'
        },
        'ios': <String, dynamic>{
          'iconName': 'AppIcon40x40',
          'handleType': '',
          'supportsVideo': true,
          'maximumCallGroups': 2,
          'maximumCallsPerCallGroup': 1,
          'audioSessionMode': 'default',
          'audioSessionActive': true,
          'audioSessionPreferredSampleRate': 44100.0,
          'audioSessionPreferredIOBufferDuration': 0.005,
          'supportsDTMF': true,
          'supportsHolding': true,
          'supportsGrouping': false,
          'supportsUngrouping': false,
          'ringtonePath': 'Ringtone.caf'
        }
      };
      await NotificationIncomingCall.showCallkitIncoming(params);
    });
  }

  Future<void> endCurrentCall() async {
    var params = <String, dynamic>{'id': this._currentUuid};
    await NotificationIncomingCall.endCall(params);
  }

  Future<void> startOutGoingCall() async {
    this._currentUuid = _uuid.v4();
    var params = <String, dynamic>{
      'id': this._currentUuid,
      'nameCaller': 'Hien Nguyen',
      'handle': '0123456789',
      'type': 1,
      'extra': <String, dynamic>{'userId': '1a2b3c4d'},
      'ios': <String, dynamic>{'handleType': 'number'}
    }; //number/email
    await NotificationIncomingCall.startCall(params);
  }

  Future<void> activeCalls() async {
    var calls = await NotificationIncomingCall.activeCalls();
    print(calls);
  }
}
```